# Not sure how to convert callback style to Promise

Tags: node.js

I am trying to convert from old way of writing callbacks to Promise and Async using util.promisify . I am really confused and not sure how to do. If someone can help me with one of these , i can go ahead with all my other classes.

```
const pool = require("../db");

module.exports = {
  AddDish: (data, callback) => {
    pool.query(
      `insert into seller(FirstName, LastName, Phone, TimeToContact, Street, City, State, ZipCode, Country, FoodPermit, FoodPermitImage, GovtIdImage, CuisineSpecialize, CookDay, CookTimeFrom, CookTimeTo, Experience, HearAboutUs, Interests) values(?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)`,
      [
        data.firstName,
        data.lastName,
        data.phone,
        data.timeToContact,
        data.street,
        data.city,
        data.state,
        data.zipCode,
        data.country,
        data.foodPermit,
        data.foodPermitImage,
        data.govtIdImage,
        data.cuisineSpecialize,
        data.cookDay,
        data.cookTimeFrom,
        data.cookTimeTo,
        data.experience,
        data.hearAboutUs,
        data.interests,
        // data.sellerReference, //Optional Attribute
        // data.dateCreated, //Autogenerated
        // data.dateModified, //Autogenerated
      ],
      (error, results, fields) => {
        if (error) {
          return callback(error);
        }
        return callback(null, results);
      }
    );
  },
getSellers: (callback) => {
    pool.query(
      `select FirstName, LastName, Phone, TimeToContact, Street, City, State, ZipCode, Country, FoodPermit, FoodPermitImage, GovtIdImage, CuisineSpecialize, CookDay, CookTimeFrom, CookTimeTo, Experience, HearAboutUs, Interests from seller`,
      [],
      (error, results, fields) => {
        if (error) {
          return callback(error);
        }
        return callback(null, results);
      }
    );
  },
};
```

Answer (score 0):

As far as i know `pool.query` returns an Promise if you dont provide an callback, then you will just need to return the query like this:

```
module.exports = {
  AddDish: data => {
    return pool.query(
      `insert into seller(FirstName, LastName, Phone, TimeToContact, Street, City, State, ZipCode, Country, FoodPermit, FoodPermitImage, GovtIdImage, CuisineSpecialize, CookDay, CookTimeFrom, CookTimeTo, Experience, HearAboutUs, Interests) values(?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)`,
      [
        data.firstName,
        data.lastName,
        data.phone,
        data.timeToContact,
        data.street,
        data.city,
        data.state,
        data.zipCode,
        data.country,
        data.foodPermit,
        data.foodPermitImage,
        data.govtIdImage,
        data.cuisineSpecialize,
        data.cookDay,
        data.cookTimeFrom,
        data.cookTimeTo,
        data.experience,
        data.hearAboutUs,
        data.interests
        // data.sellerReference, //Optional Attribute
        // data.dateCreated, //Autogenerated
        // data.dateModified, //Autogenerated
      ]
    );
  },
  getSellers: () => {
    return pool.query(
      `select FirstName, LastName, Phone, TimeToContact, Street, City, State, ZipCode, Country, FoodPermit, FoodPermitImage, GovtIdImage, CuisineSpecialize, CookDay, CookTimeFrom, CookTimeTo, Experience, HearAboutUs, Interests from seller`,
      []
    );
  }
};
```

Comment: I am not sure if the select statement should be there or there is some other way to handle the return